# Writing a program that creates parallel arrays for a string based on the alphabet and the letters' indexes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that will take in a string and create 2 vectors. Then, it will sort each letter in the string alphabetically. As it sorts each letter, I want it to also insert a value with the same index as the letter(corresponds). The conditions will be:

if the letter inserted was the first element of the string, the value inserted into the second vector will be 0.

if the letter inserted was the first or last element of the vector, the value inserted into the second vector will be the value of the adjacent vector plus 1

Otherwise, insert a value that is 1 plus the larger of the two adjacent values(the values of the letters beside the current letter).

*Note that if there is another copy of the current letter being inserted, put the current letter being inserted in front of the "before" letter.

So far, I made the code that sorts the letters alphabetically, but I can't insert the values into the right places. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
typedef long long ll;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string input;
    cin>>input;
    vector<char> sorted_chars;
    vector<int> sorted_values;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        char c = input[i];
        int index = 0;
        while (index < sorted_chars.size() && c >= sorted_chars[index]) {//index less than size, keeps increasing until c is less than the next element
            index++;
        }
        sorted_chars.insert(sorted_chars.begin() + index, c);//sort for first vector
        int value;
        if(i==0){                             //   first element
            sorted_values.push_back(0);
        }
        else if(index==(sorted_chars.size()-1)){   //   last of vector 1
            value=sorted_values[index - 1] + 1;
            sorted_values.insert(sorted_values.begin()+index,value);
        }
        else if(index==0){                         //   first of vector 1
            value=sorted_values[1]+1;
            sorted_values.insert(sorted_values.begin()+index,value);
        }
        else{
            value=max(sorted_values[index-1],sorted_values[index])+1;
            sorted_values.insert(sorted_values.begin()+index,value);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<sorted_chars.size();++i){
        cout<<sorted_chars[i];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<sorted_values.size();++i){
        cout<<sorted_values[i]<< " ";
    }    
}
```

But I don't get the right values for the second vector. Heres an example of what the result should be:

for PYTHONN

Iteration 1:

vector 1- P

vector 2- 0

Iteration 2:

vector 1- PY

vector 2- 01

Iteration 3:

vector 1- PTY

vector 2- 021

Iteration 4:

vector 1-HPTY

vector 2-1021

Iteration 5:

vector 1-HOPTY

vector 2-12021

Iteration 6:

vector 1-HNOPTY

vector 2-132021

Iteration 7:

vector 1-HNNOPTY

vector 2-1432021

I feel like there's something wrong with the else statement but I'm not sure what it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw 2 issues in your code.

In search of index, if character is not new, we have to insert **before**. So the test is :

```
        int index = 0;
        while (index < sorted_chars.size() && c > sorted_chars[index]){//index less than size, keeps increasing until c is less than the next element
            index++;
        }
```

or simply use the function made for that

```
        int index = std::lower_bound(sorted_chars.begin(), sorted_chars.end(), c) - sorted_chars.begin();
```

And an error in index taken in the case where index is null.

```
        else if(index==0){                         //   first of vector 1
            value=sorted_values[ 0 ]+1;  // next is still at 0 before insertion
            sorted_values.insert(sorted_values.begin()+index,value);
        }
```